# Dynamic window width in JQuery (mobile rotator)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery rotator in my website with a slides images and I want to make the website responsive. I'm using CSS media queries to do it. I want to change the slide width (which defines in JS) when the windows width is less than 800px. So long, I did something like this:

```
var responsiveSlideWidth;

if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    responsiveSlideWidth = 700;
}
else {
    responsiveSlideWidth = 960;
}


var defaults = {
    container: '.rotatorWrapper',
    animationduration: 1000,
    slideWidth: responsiveSlideWidth
};
```

The problem is that it is working just after page reload. Thats means: if I resize the window size its is not working well until I reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    // your code
});
```

It will trigger every time the window is resized.

Comment: How did you try it exactly? Showing the rest of your code would help aswell